# How could I find the fields of a SharePoint list from database in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: xml, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, field, sharepoint-list

In SharePoint 2003 and 2007, there was a table called AllLists which had a column called tp_Fields which contained an xml containing all fields for a specific list.

an example of the xml stored in the tp_Fields column would be this for a SharePoint List with 3 fields:

```
<FieldRef Name="ContentTypeId" />
<FieldRef Name="_ModerationComments" ColName="ntext1" />
<FieldRef Name="WebPartTypeName" ColName="nvarchar9" />
```

We have an application that is reading from this column using C# code e.g.

```
var tpFields = (String) drView["tp_Fields"];
```

In SharePoint 2010, the datatype of this column has changed to **varbinary** and contains just some binary data instead!

(I know the ideal/recommended solution was to use the SharePoint web services or SharePoint object model and not relying on the underlying tables but unfortunately we have an existing app and we'd need to make it work with 2010 as well. I hope we don't have to redesign everything!)

How could I know what fields a SharePoint list has from its database in SharePoint 2010? or if possible how to convert this varbinary column to its equivalent xml like before?

I hope the question is clear (have little hope about its possibility tbh).

Thanks,

Comment: Is this using the server object model, web services, or what?

Comment: the existing system is using database table like I said.

Comment: Is this a batch job?  A web part?  Is the code running on the server?  Can you use the server object model in your code (even if it's just for this section)?  Is this even .NET code, or is it using some other paradigm entirely?  If so, what is it?

Comment: I added some more notes in the question. The C# code reads from the database structure in order to generate some views from it later (I can't use web service or object model for this because the views which are generated will also use the underlying sharepoint tables ...).

Comment: I didn't say rewrite the entire application to use the server object model (although I do think you dug yourself into this hole by relying on internal underlying implementations).  I said use the server object model to get the fields for the list(s) and then keep doing whatever else you're doing until that code gets broken too.

Comment: thanks but like I said I can't use the server object model; need to be using the database directly. I know it's a crab design!

Comment: You never said that you couldn't use the sever object model, you just said that you weren't.  That's entirely different.  Why can't you?

Comment: isn't the SharePoint object model the same thing as Server object model? maybe you mean something else? but anyway, the reason is a long story. we have many systems which use views on top of the SharePoint tables and those views are created by this application. those views read the underlying sharepoint tables...

Comment: The server object model is what the 'object model' is called in 2010 because in 2010 there is both a server object model and a client object model.  The client object model didn't exist in 2007 so there was no need for a distinction.

Comment: As I've said twice now, you don't need to create/alter your views using the object model, you can do all of that stuff using exactly what you have now (if it still works).  You asked how to find all of the columns in a list because you can't do so via the DB.  You can do that via the server object model very easily.  Just because you fetch the data using the server object model doesn't mean you can't update the views directly through the DB.

Comment: plz leave it Servy; you didn't understand the question. "How could I find the fields of a SharePoint list from database in SharePoint 2010?" - I'd need to read from database directly. don't worry; thanks for the try anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to share, I wrote the below method and it can now extract the xml from it although there is no quarantee the resulting xml is compatible with SharePoint 2003/2007.

```
 private static string getXmlFromTpFields(byte[] tpFields)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(tpFields))
            {
                // ignore the first 14 bytes; I'm not sure why but it works!
                for (var index = 0; index <= 13; index++)
                    memoryStream.ReadByte();

                var deflateStream = new DeflateStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);

                using (var destination = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    deflateStream.CopyTo(destination);

                    var streamReader = new StreamReader(destination);
                    destination.Position = 0;
                    return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing this for a long time and found a utility program named [SPViews](http://sharpesttoolsoftware.com/).  You point it at the content database and it generates the SQL script to create the views for you.  It reads the compressed field to get the columns and generates the script.  You can get the columns from there.

jd