# SharePoint 2010 Lists tp_fields - not in XML?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I have a requirement to report directly on SharePoint data, and I am looking to use the tp_fields data from Lists table to get the mapping between the SQL column name (nvarchar1, nvarchar2,ntext1,int1 etc.) and SharePoint list column name. I will then create some SQL views which represents my data in a more understandable format (that mirrors the SharePoint list.)

This should be in XML format within tp_fields, however I just get the below:

0xA8A930310C000000B4260000789CD55A896EDB4812FD152E77334880698B47F38A6D011E1F13617D04B193 (...but much, much longer!)

Any ideas how to convert this to the XML? Or what the issue is? From my research, the tp_fields should contain a direct mapping between nvarchar1 and SharePoint list field name. But all of the examples I can find for this are around SP 2007 - has something changed between the 2? Is there anywhere else I can find this mapping?

Thanks,

Comment: Before you go any further, may i ask why don't you want to use object model or webservices to query SharePoint data in the way that it is supposed to be queried?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2010 compresses that `tp_Fields` column now. There are answers elsewhere that show how to decompress it. For example:

[How could I find the fields of a SharePoint list from database in SharePoint 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988098/how-could-i-find-the-fields-of-a-sharepoint-list-from-database-in-sharepoint-201)

or

[SharePoint 2010 Content database](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/sharepoint2010programming/thread/27e47732-9528-446c-9c09-7ab968e11e42)